# Could not find Qt platform plugin 'xcb' on Debian 8.3

Tags: c++, qt

I've compiled a simple Qt application on Ubuntu 15.10.
I've created a lib and a platforms folder int the same directory where the executable is.
I've copied libicudata.so.54, libicui18n.so.54, libicuuc.so.54,   libQt5Core.so.5, libQt5DBus.so.5, libQt5Gui.so.5, libQt5Widgets.so.5,
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 into lib, and libxcb.so into platforms,
then moved the   application with the folders to a fresh Debian 8.3 install.
I've also created a start.sh script with the following content:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/lib
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=$PWD/platforms
./QtTestApp
```

But when I start the application using the script it says that it couldn't find Qt platform plugin 'xcb'...
I've run `ldd` on the application itself, and on the libxcb.so also, but it seems, it have found everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"platforms" is a subfolder of the plugins directory.

Sample structure

```
./QtTestApp
./qt.conf
./lib
./lib/libicudata.so.54
./lib/libicui18n.so.54
…
./lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
./plugins/platforms
./plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
./plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so
./plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so
./plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so
```

with `qt.conf`

```
[Paths]
Prefix = .
```

In this case, you usually do not need to set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH can also be avoided if you set the RPATH of `./QtTestApp` to `$ORIGIN/lib`.

---

Note: it is likely that your application compiled on Ubuntu 15.10 does not run on Debian 8. This is because Ubuntu 15.10 uses a newer version of libc and libstdc++, which is not available on Debian 8. You can work around that issue when you use Ubuntu 14.04 as the compile machine. Then you have approximately [this list of compatible target distributions](https://www.kullo.net/en/supported-linux-distributions/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem starting with the warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform...
Which is missleading because it turned out to be a plugin missing within the deploy. Here is what I did: I copied the "xcbglintegrations" folder from within the "plugins" folder of the qt installation on the dev-system (in my case under "Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins") to the deployed app folder into a "plugins" folder. It is then sufficient to supply an empty(!) qt.conf file into the app folder which overwrites the hard-coded library paths with the defaults of the qt.conf-method (which is in case of the "plugins" folder a relative "plugins" folder as described). Look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) for more info on the qt.conf file and the defaults. I found this as I had problems specifying the path within the qt.conf file to be recognized correctly in the first place. The correct complete way for the qt.conf file (and recommended instead of an empty file of cause) is:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = .
Plugins = plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, Debian packaged the Qt XCB plugin separately from Qt GUI library, and it looks like you have this version.  Two options:

- install `libqt5xcbqpa5`
- upgrade `libqt5gui5`

Comment: Just re-read the question - what are you copying libraries around for?  Just leave them where they are installed - that's what the package manager is for!